# perl - Remove line of data containing X

Tags: perl

I would like to ignore each line of a file that contains words listed into `remove.txt`.

How can I modify the command below which does not work even if `remove.txt` contains the word `privacy`.

```
cat remove.txt | 
  perl -n0E 's/\n/|/g; say "print unless m!@($_=)\\b!i\n" ' > AUX
perl -n AUX   Filelist.txt > outfile
```

Here is an example of my data:

```
"albu*****holmes**","ab***foo@bar.com","aef" *22","Angel**or","FR","2***3","FRANCE"
"copperhill*****omes**","pg***trj@whoisprivacyprotect.com","***ox *39","Kir**and","WA","9***3","UNITED STATES"
"ironhill*****shelock**","dd***trejo@foo.com","***oxtho *42","Kiss**or","CA","2***3","UNITED STATES"
```

You see that the second entry contains the word `privacy`. So it should not appear in the output.

So eventually I want to get this:

```
"albu*****holmes**","ab***foo@bar.com","aef" *22","Angel**or","FR","2***3","FRANCE"
"ironhill*****shelock**","dd***trejo@foo.com","***oxtho *42","Kiss**or","CA","2***3","UNITED STATES"
```

Comment: That line should be removed because it contains "privacy" which is in remove.txt - It only seems to remove words that end in privacy, for example abc@xyz.privacy

Comment: The main problem is that your regex is nonsense. The `AUX` file contains `print unless m!@(privacy|xxx|yyy|=)\b!i` and I don't see what you're trying to do with the `@` and the `=`. You also have a word boundary `\b` at the end, so it won't match something like `whoisprivacyprotect`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your last comment, you have a file named `Filelist.txt` that contain data like this:

```
"albu*****holmes**","ab***foo@bar.com","aef" *22","Angel**or","FR","2***3","FRANCE"
"copperhill*****omes**","pg***trj@whoisprivacyprotect.com","***ox *39","Kir**and","WA","9***3","UNITED STATES"
"ironhill*****shelock**","dd***trejo@foo.com","***oxtho *42","Kiss**or","CA","2***3","UNITED STATES"
```

You want to remove each entry that contain words mentionned in the file `remove.txt`. This file looks like:

```
privacy
standard
lucy
```

Any of the entry that match any of these words will be skipped.

If I follow your philosophy, you first want to build a regex from the words in `remove.txt`, then apply this regex to your file.

So from the `remove.txt` shown above, we want to get this:

```
m/(privacy|standard|lucy)/i
```

We need to quotemeta to make sure words like `remo\nve` will be properly escaped:

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp; push @words, quotemeta; END{print "m/(".join("|",@words).")/i"}' remove
m/(privacy|standard|lucy)/i
```

If you don't need to escape invalid characters you can use

```
$ cat remove.txt | tr '\n' '|' | awk '{print "m/("$0")/i"}'
m/(privacy|standard|lucy)/i
```

Your second step is to apply this regex in your data

```
$ cat filelist.txt | perl -ne "print unless `cat regex`"
"albu*****holmes**","ab***foo@bar.com","aef" *22","Angel**or","FR","2***3","FRANCE"
"ironhill*****shelock**","dd***trejo@foo.com","***oxtho *42","Kiss**or","CA","2***3","UNITED STATES"
```

However thing can be simpler with grep:

```
$ cat filelist.txt | egrep -v `cat remove.txt | tr '\n' '|'`
```

In all of this be careful that you don't have any trailing `\n` in you file `remove.txt` because you regex will become `m/(a|b|c|)/i` instead of `m/(a|b|c)/i` which will match everything.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but both of these gave errors. First ---- Scalar found where operator expected at ./A line 4, near ")
$re"
        (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Can't modify concatenation (.) or string in scalar assignment at ./A line 4, near "<$fp>)
"
syntax error at ./A line 4, near ")
$re "
syntax error at ./A line 5, near "/$re/ while"
Execution of ./A aborted due to compilation errors. ----- The second error gave 
syntax error at -e line 4, near "/$re/ while"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Edit your question and I'll give you a working answer

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am getting "cat: remove: No such file or directory" - None of the commands you posted include remove.txt, how can I use that? I need to load them from a file as there are several thousand entries.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a similar way, but all within one Perl program

Here's an example. It expects both the input files as parameters on the command line, so you would run it as

```
perl program.pl remove.txt Filelist.txt
```

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my @lines = do {
  open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];
  <$fh>;
};
chomp @lines;
my $re = join '|', @lines;
$re = qr/(?:$re)/;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[1];
while ( <$fh> ) {
  print unless /$re/;
}
```

#### output

```
"albu*****holmes**","ab***foo@bar.com","aef" *22","Angel**or","FR","2***3","FRANCE"
"ironhill*****shelock**","dd***trejo@foo.com","***oxtho *42","Kiss**or","CA","2***3","UNITED STATES"
```

Comment: This gives perl errors. Do I need to install something? - Can't locate autodie.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at p.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at p.pl line 4.

Comment: @KenRenalds: Yes, it requires `autodie` which was introduced in Perl v5.10.1. I added `use 5.010` to check for that. Have you fallen through the gap, and are running v5.10.0? The easiest fix is probably to install `autodie` from CPAN. Or you could upgrade Perl, or delete the last two `use` statements and add `or die $!` to the end of each `open` statement?